# How to select the nth HTML row in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select the nth row of a HTML table knowing only the id of a selected row. 
This is my situation: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/896kxjn1/11/)

```
<table class="mytable1">
    <tr><td id="12">1.0</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="20">1.1</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="120">1.2</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="260">1.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="2">1.4</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="100">1.5</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="23">1.6</td></tr>
</table>
```

For example i want to fadeOut the 2th `<tr>` from the row i know its id, in this case fadout animation has to be launched on `<tr><td id="260">1.3</td></tr>`

To be more clear, this is the final desired result:

```
$("#"+"260").closest("tr").fadeOut();
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the `+""` at the end of the selector meant to be doing?

Comment: The JSFiddle appears to be working. Are you wanting to dynamically assign the ID number?

Comment: I don't want to fadeout the selected row, but the nth row after the selected one!

Comment: How do you decide what `n` is?

Comment: Please look at http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: @OmriAharon the n value comes from another jquery function, which return an int value

Comment: Hey I guess I done some hurry. The fiddle was working well but there were extra "" added at end.Is there any other specification as told by ilan berci there is a way to select nth child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to get nth row *after* the known one, you can do something like this using `index` and `:eq` selector:

```
var n = 2;
var index = $("#20").closest("tr").index() + n;
$('.mytable1 tr:eq(' + index + ')').fadeOut();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/896kxjn1/14/

Comment: Would this still be true for a dynamically created table, or a table where you can shift rows around?

Comment: I can't see why not. With id you still will get correct row, and after that you will count necessary rows with `eq`.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the index of the element inside the table *:nth-child(index)* can be a solution,

```
$("table tr:nth-child(2)").fadeOut();
```

And if you know the id only, not the index then get the index of that element,

```
// added 1 as .index() is indexed with 0 but in :nth-child(n) n is indexed 1
var elementIndex = $("#20").parent().index() + 1;
$("table tr:nth-child(" + elementIndex + ")").fadeOut();
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/eoqLuurm/)

***Resources :***  [***:nth-child(index)***](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), [***.index()***](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 1):

*i want to fadeOut the 2th  from the row*

Then you can just do this with `:eq(index)`:

```
 $('.mytable1 tr:eq(1)').fadeOut();
```

As `:eq()` is `zero, 0` based so it's index starts from 0, so the second item is at index 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `nextAll` and then by index:

`$("#"+"20"+"").closest("tr").nextAll('tr').eq(n-1).fadeOut();`

This way, you don't have to start at the table itself if you don't want to.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/896kxjn1/16/)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are million better ways to do this using features of jQuery I wasn't even aware existed.

But, I'll post my answer for the sake of showing a fair, procedural way to accomplish this. It may help someone understand the thought processes behind solving this problem.

```
// Create an array of tr elements from your table
row_list = $('table.mytable1 tr');

// Get the actual DOM element selected by jQuery with [0]
selected_row = $("#"+"20").closest("tr")[0];

// Use some function to set "nth"
nth_add = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < row_list.length; i++) {
    // Find the index of the current element, and add nth
    if (row_list[i] == selected_row) {
        select_new_index = i + nth_add;
        break;
    }
}

// Perform your manipulation on the index + nth element.
$(row_list[select_new_index]).fadeOut();
```

And here is the [updated JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/896kxjn1/19/)